# Assign buffer-name to variable

Tags: buffers, interactive

I'd like to write `Elisp` code that compares text character by character between two buffers.

To do that, I need to first assign buffer names to the variables `source-buffer` and `target-buffer` respectively.

```el
(defun set-source-buffer (&optional buffer)
  "Sets source-buffer to current-buffer. "
  (interactive "bSelect Source Buffer: \nr" buffer)
  (cond ((boundp 'buffer) buffer)
        (setq source-buffer (current-buffer))))
```

I would like to call this function by either activating the buffer to be selected as source and do `(setq source-buffer (current-buffer))` or use `(set-source-buffer buffer)` in code, whereby `buffer` is the name of the buffer to be selected.

The above code returns `nil` when run on an active buffer.

How do I fix this?

---

## Update:

I refer to the `if` statement provided by @Hubisan below.

```
(defun my-set-source-buffer (&optional buffer-or-name)
  "Sets `my-source-buffer' to `current-buffer' unless BUFFER-OR-NAME is given.
BUFFER-OR-NAME can be a string of an existing buffer or a buffer object."
  (interactive "bSelect Source Buffer:")
  (setq my-source-buffer
    (if (buffer-live-p (get-buffer buffer))
        (get-buffer buffer)
      (current-buffer))))
```

When should we use `buffer-or-name` for a variable and when to use just `buffer` alone?

Comment: "The above code yields a void function buffer error." is not true. It does complain that there are not enough arguments, as you have (seemingly inexplicably) included a second interactive code r after the b -- which means the function needs to accept a pair of region delimiter arguments as well. I'm not seeing any way that the code you've shown could result in the error you've quoted.  Please try to sanity-check your questions to check that what you state is happening is actually what is happening.

Comment: Yes - you are right! The only issue with the above code is that it returns `nil` when run on an active buffer.

Comment: @Sati just forgot to change the if part, sorry for that. fixed.

Comment: From my understanding, to have a working function, either `buffer` or `buffer-or-name` can be used, so long as the upper part right after the `defun` - the defined arguments to the function - and variables called within the body of the function itself agree. Is that correct? So `buffer-or-name` is just a convention to indicate that the function accepts either a string of an existing buffer or a buffer object as its argument? (any other symbol can be used in its place from a functional perspective)

Comment: @Sati Exactly. I always try to find a function that has a similar argument to sort of copy the common symbol used for it. `buffer-or-name` is used in many functions as argument so it's a good idea to use the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `cond` to bind either the buffer provided or the current buffer to my-source-buffer. No need for the extra line below. As there is actually only one condition an if statement would probably serve you better.
- For the interactive line: Don't include the buffer variable. See [Using-Interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).
- `(boundp 'buffer)` also returns `t` if `buffer` is nil as the symbol itself exists because it is an argument of the function. To check if buffer was provided a simple `(when buffer ...)` is enough.
- It's advisable to prefix custom variables and functions with for instance `my-`. See [Elisp > Coding-Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html). Adapted the names in the following code accordingly.

```lisp
(defun my-set-source-buffer (&optional buffer-or-name)
  "Sets `my-source-buffer' to `current-buffer' unless BUFFER-OR-NAME is given.
BUFFER-OR-NAME can be a string of an existing buffer or a buffer object."
  (interactive "bSelect Source Buffer:")
  (setq my-source-buffer
        (cond
         ;; Check if buffer is a buffer and if it still exists.
         ;; `get-buffer' is used to get the buffer by name if needed.
         ((buffer-live-p (get-buffer buffer-or-name)) (get-buffer buffer-or-name))
         ;; Otherwise return the current buffer.
         (t (current-buffer))))
  ;; Same with using if statement.
  ;; (setq my-source-buffer
  ;;       (if (buffer-live-p (get-buffer buffer-or-name))
  ;;           (get-buffer buffer-or-name)
  ;;         (current-buffer)))
  )
```

The function can be called as follows:

- with string of an existing buffer: `(my-set-source-buffer "*scratch*")`
- with a buffer object: `(my-set-source-buffer (get-buffer "*scratch*"))`
- interactively: <kbd>M-x my-set-source-buffer</kbd> and select the buffer interactively.

Comment: `(and (bufferp b) (buffer-live-p b))` = `(buffer-live-p b)`. See `C-h f buffer-live-p`.

Comment: The `interactive` form will give a buffer *name*, but the code you've written checks for a buffer object. One of them should be adjusted.

Comment: @npostavs thx for the input. Fixed the function.